# Using leaflet-control-geocoder with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, geocoding, react-leaflet

I want to use `react-leaflet` and to add a geocoder field on top of it. I found `leaflet-control-geocoder` which seems great but no react wrapper to use it with react-leaflet. Anyone has done this and can share a sandbox? Or maybe it exists on GitHub and i did not use the right keywords ?

Thanks for your help,
Best regards

Comment: The latest 3.0.5, thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `react-leaflet` **v.3.x**

Create your own wrapper:

install `leaflet-control-geocoder`
and import its dependencies:

```
import "leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css";
import "leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js";
```

Use the code from [demo](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder/tree/master/demo) to build your React wrapper.

```
function LeafletControlGeocoder() {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim();
    if (typeof URLSearchParams !== "undefined" && location.search) {
      // parse /?geocoder=nominatim from URL
      var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      var geocoderString = params.get("geocoder");
      if (geocoderString && L.Control.Geocoder[geocoderString]) {
        geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder[geocoderString]();
      } else if (geocoderString) {
        console.warn("Unsupported geocoder", geocoderString);
      }
    }

    L.Control.geocoder({
      query: "",
      placeholder: "Search here...",
      defaultMarkGeocode: false,
      geocoder
    })
      .on("markgeocode", function (e) {
        var latlng = e.geocode.center;
        L.marker(latlng, { icon })
          .addTo(map)
          .bindPopup(e.geocode.name)
          .openPopup();
        map.fitBounds(e.geocode.bbox);
      })
      .addTo(map);
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

Import it as MapContainer child

```
  <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
     ...
      <LeafletControlGeocoder />
  </MapContainer>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-leaflet-control-geocoder-with-react-leaflet-v3x-63wqz)

Comment: This is a great answer.  I may also suggest using a wrapper I wrote: [react-esri-leaflet's `EsriLeafletGeoSearch`](https://github.com/slutske22/react-esri-leaflet#using-esri-leaflet-plugins)

Comment: @SethLutske can you use your wrapper with Nominatim?

Comment: My plugin is a react wrapper for esri-leaflet, so its has all the same options as esri-leaflet's geocoder.  Their docs show that you can use [these providers](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/controls/geosearch.html#providers) with it, which doesn't look like it includes nominatim.  I think you'll have to use kbouls answer and make your own if you want to specifically use nominatim.

Comment: If you need to pass in query params to nominatim it can be done like: `let geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({geocodingQueryParams: {limit: 2,countrycodes: 'us',},});`